# Xamarin.IOS UIBarbuttonItem added as in Recipe does not work. No error no button

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Using Xamarin IOS app derived from The Tabbed Application template. Targeting IOS 11+; testing in simulator for 12.1.

I added a UINavigationBar to one of The UIView tabs and tried to add a save and cancel button into The bar.

No error, no joy, The NavigationItem is NOT null, and shows The correct Navigation Item.  Here is The outline:

```
--UIViewController MyInfoController
----UIView InfoView
------UINavigationBar NavBar
--------UINavigationItem [no name]
------UIView ContentView
------A bunch of constraints
----UITabBar
```

and here is a relevant snippet of The code:

```
    public partial class MyInfoController : UIViewController
{
    protected MyInfoController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
            new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save, (sender, args) => 
            {
                // Handle Save Button Click here.
                //Create Alert
                var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Click", "Right Button Clicked.", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                //Add Action
                okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                // Present Alert
                PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
            }), true);


        // Try another way...

        var button = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel,  (sender, e) =>
        { 
            //Put Something here 
        });

        button.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
        {
            TextColor = UIColor.White,
            TextShadowColor = UIColor.Clear
        }, UIControlState.Normal);

        this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(button, true);
        // Create and add Views
```

No error messages issue.  I don't see anything wrong, but I also don't see The bar button items.

What am I missing? (:-S)

Comment: Do you use `UINavigationController` as the `RootViewController` of `InfoController`.According to provided code,I don't see that.

Comment: Sorry, please pardon the confused noob. MyInfoController is a UIVewController, and does not even have rootviewcontroller as a member.  UIViewController is invoked via a UITabBarController.

Comment: Where is your `UINavigationBar` and `UINavigationItem` ,can you expode code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ios designer to add `UINavigationBar` and `UINavigationItem` ,you'd better set name for them ,like this

```
------UINavigationBar NavBar
--------UINavigationItem BarItem
```

So , in the controller , bar will show normally.

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        this.BarItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save, (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Handle Save Button Click here.
            //Create Alert
            var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Click", "Right Button Clicked.", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            //Add Action
            okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            // Present Alert
            PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
        }), true);


        // Try another way...

        var button = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Put Something here 
        });

        button.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
        {
            TextColor = UIColor.Black,
            TextShadowColor = UIColor.Clear
        }, UIControlState.Normal);

        this.BarItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(button, true);
    }
```

More info:

If you use `this.NavigationItem` ,this commonly used in root controller is `UINavigationController` .

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly!  I truly appreciate your patience with a noob.